# Как заменить нужный символ в каждой строке

Tags: linux, sed

Есть текстовые файлы, в которых мне необходимо заменить знак * на /.

Как это сделать в консоли линукса?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's/\*/\//g' file.txt
```

опция -i переписывает содержимое файла

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | sed "s/*/\//g" >file.new
```

В общем то и добавить нечего, sed отлично меняет символы :)